# Manipulate 3d models in adobe Flash

Tags: flash

I'm trying to create a 3D model from sketchup then manipulate the image in Adobe Flash like rotate the image. What's tools or applications do I need to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Flash supports 3D, but you can't manipulate it in the Flash Pro Editor.
You need to use stage3D api to render 3D. The easiest way to do so is to use Away3D at http://away3d.com/
They also provide tools to import 3D files and compose 3d scenes: http://awaytools.com/awaybuilder/live-tool/